# Can a parent div shrink smaller than the min-width of one of its children?

Tags: css

On initial page load the parent is wider than 500px. I need a horizontal scroll bar to appear in the parent when it becomes less than 500px wide. The problem is setting the min-width of the child makes it so the parent does not shrink below 500px. What needs to be changed so that the parent can shrink below 500px?

```css
    .parent {
      overflow-x:auto;
    }
    .child {
       width:500px;
       min-width:500px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            elements and such
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `I need a horizontal scroll bar to appear in the parent` This is not possible, for a scrollbar to appear the element needs a limit *(a set width)* and `overflow` property set to auto or scroll. In your case only one constraint is met.

Comment: @ZohirSalak so, ignore the scrollbar issue. I know how that works. The problem I am having is how can the parent shrink to smaller than the min-width of one of its children?

Comment: The code you posted does exactly what you want - I've put it into a working snippet, so just resize the browser and you'll see. If it's not working in your site, then you have something else that's affecting how it works. Please show us all the relevant code in a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem. We can't fix a problem that doesn't exist in the code we see!